# Swift - Naming Function Type Parameters

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am trying to find a way to name function type parameters for my case. To be more clear, let me share a bit of code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var testView: TestView = {
        let view = TestView()
        view.action = action
        return view
    }()
    
    func action() {
        //stuff
    }
    
}

class TestView: UIView {
    
    var action: () -> () = {}
    
    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        action()
    }
}
```

Code above is working well injecting `UIButton` actions from `View` to `Controller` but it becomes worse when there are parameters to be passed through. When I try to change the `action` inside `TestView` to,

```
var action: (name: String, surname: String) -> () = { _, _ in }
```

it does not let me to name `String` parameters. Afterwards I tried to change it as using tuple,

```
var action: ((name: String, surname: String)) -> () = { _ in }
```

the code inside the `TestView` works. However I can not match the types `view.action = action` in `ViewController`.

I am trying to do it because of two reasons. One of which is to not have any kind of logical inside `View` and other one is easily identify and avoid confusion the parameters inside `ViewController` by its given name when there are 2+ parameters that is going to be sent to the `Controller`.

Lastly, I know I can use delegation. But it has its own problems in my opinion. I am already have been trying to decrease `Delegate`s in the project since I started to struggle naming the protocols.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, we've been up and down this road. For technical reasons you cannot use parameter labels in a function _type_. It was possible for a while IIRC but then the universe started to implode.

Comment: What was your solution then? If you are able to share, of course @matt

Comment: There really is nothing you can do about it. If you look at Apple's own code, it suffers from the same issue. They can declare a typealias like https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/supplementaryviewprovider, but if you want to know what the parameters _mean_, there are no labels to tell you; you have to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swift does not allow named parameters in function declaration, so you can do like the following:

```
class TestView: UIView {
    
//    var action: () -> () = {}
    var action: (_ name: String , _ surname: String ) -> () = { _, _ in }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        action("name", "surname")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not solve the problem for `Controller` side.

Comment: Cannot say I understood what do you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Once I changed `action()` in `Controller` to `actioon(username: String?, password:String?)` and of course with  your suggestion above it works. However, the problem here is when some reads `action("name", "surname")` like line, there is a chance they would not be able identify which is what. (like if there is not any indication like `namefield.text`). I guess, it would be fine most of the time and I may be overthinking.

Comment: I have found a solution and it is creating a `struct` with relevant `var`s in it. And pass it to the `Controller`.